# How to store a symmetric key in the Android Keystore

Tags: android, cryptography, symmetric-key

I would like to provide the security to symmetric key which I have used for encryption and decryption.
I would like to Encrypt the symmetric key and store in shared preferences.
How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is imprecise regarding what is encrypted with which key and why. You should edit it and improve your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is not a very advisable strategy.
You should never store keys in your app, since you can not trust a delivered app.

The only way to do this is to have a trusted server wich has user accounts, that use the apis that need to be secured.

[Collection of all reasons](https://rammic.github.io/2015/07/28/hiding-secrets-in-android-apps/)
[Reasons why google does not advice to do so, and counter measures](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037?hl=en)